# Implementing SCA into Stripe implementation

Tags: stripe-payments

I've making a SaaS that allows customers to subscribe to a plan, and use coupons at the checkout stage.  The coupons give the customers `X% off for X months`, and by default, everyone gets a 7 day trial when they subscribe.

What is confusing me is the documentation. In one section it says that you should create SetupIntents to take a payment and elsewhere it says to use tokens.

I'm in the middle of coding the payment flow, but I just wanted to check to see if my logic and understanding is correct. Could anyone validate the below?

1. Customer enters card number and coupon
2. Call Stripe, get token for card
3. Send token and coupon to server
4. Create Stripe customer with token
5. Create Subscription with discount and pass customer ID

What has now happened is an authorisation attempt was made. If SCA is required, then the subscription status is incomplete and the latest invoice payment intent status requires action.

At this point, I can redirect my user to the SCA Flow using `handleCardPayment()` to prompt 3DS, and once complete the subscription status is then active.

If the invoice payment fails for any reason, then the subscription state is incomplete and the payment intent requires has a payment action required status.    At this point, I should present my customer with the React Elements form again, and call the `stripe.invoices.pay` endpoint with the new card token

Going forwards, all subscription charges should not need further SCA approval, however if the customer changes plan or the bank requests it, then I can point my user back through the SCA Flow process

A diagram of the flow is here: Green is UI, Orange is Server, Blue is Stripe

[image]

Is there anything I have missed or misunderstood here?  I've been reading about creating SetupIntents and PaymentIntents, but I'm not sure I need this?

Comment: That diagram looks great to me! That is SCA-ready as-is. The only point I'd make is that in the 'next monthly payment'->'invoice generated'->'SCA needed' flow, you don't have to have a page that does `handleCardPayment` yourself, Stripe can be configured to send an email to the customer automatically https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#3ds-payment-settings But the diagram there is correct for the initial payment

Comment: Ah yes, I should have added that. For me, id like to notify the user in app to inform them additional info/new payment is needed but yes, I did see that on the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating subscriptions using the Stripe Billing product they handle creating the PaymentIntent(if you are taking a payment immediately) or a SetupIntent (if you are setting up a trial or metered billing). All that you really have to do different is handleCardPayment (for payments) or handleCardSetup (for setting up trials and metered billing). [This](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#upgrading-integration) section in the docs is pretty good.

If you are not using billing they have a [video](https://youtu.be/52oinv6BZ34) on their Stripe Developers Youtube channel which may help clear up any confusion.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome fellow sufferer, cards and tokens are implemented in [Stripe Charges API which is not SCA compilant](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication#preparing). If you want use Stripe for payments inside the EU you should use payment intents.

Card tokens are also allowed for creating payment intents.

But if you want reduce the number of necessary authentications you should use setup intents (with `usage = "off-session"`) for creating payment methods and not card tokens.

I have a lot of old customers who have still registered with the Charges API. I use the following strategy:

- New customers always register via Setup Intents and Payment Methods.
- Old customers use the Charges API until their tokens become invalid. Then they must also use setup intents and payment methods.

Of course, the customers do not notice much of it.

In summary, I would always use payment methods and setup intents for new customers and card updates. Only with the setup intents can you ensure that your customers have to authenticate themselves as rarely as possible.

**EDIT**: The crucial point is off-session payments that occur with subscriptions. The Stripe procedure is described here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards#saving-card-without-payment

Comment: Hmm now i'm even more confused.  I was told that subscriptions generate a PaymentIntent on invoice creation, hence why thinking that I can still call `customers.create` followed by `subscriptions.create` as per: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment

Comment: I don't use the subscriptions API but I think the page could be a little bit outdated. Payment methods should also work with payment methods in any case: „A Customer is your buyer. Customers have a unique ID, an email address, and payment methods.“ If you need SCA you should use payment methods not card tokens / sources.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to worry about off-session payments in that manner though. It states "Use the Setup Intents API when you want to collect card details up front, but you’re not sure when or how much you intend to charge the customer in the future."  This would be useful for a metered type subscription, but I'm already creating a customer and subscription for them, so I know how much i'l be charging.  If they change subscription, a new invoice is generated and the price is there.  The issue I have is its not explicitly clear what to do in my scenario..

Comment: SetupIntents don't really apply to you, since you have an initial payment from the subscription. The subscription generates a PaymentIntent yep, and you're 100% correct to follow stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment  on this.

Comment: @clemens your flow is correct, if you're doing one-off future payments, or building your own subscription logic. Otherwise if you're using Stripe's Billing APIs, those are built on top of all that(so that for example, invoices are automatically creating PaymentIntents with `off_session:true` internally, and so on)

Comment: You only need to use SetupIntents if you're not charging the customer at the time you accept their card. Otherwise you complete a PaymentIntent with `setup_future_usage:off_session` , or just create a subscription and handle the payment of its invoice(and it automatically sets that usage too, on the PaymentIntent the invoice created)

Comment: @karllekko Yes, you‘re right about setup intents. But my most important point is not to use tokens but payment methods.

Comment: True, although you can build an SCA-ready flow using tokens too, there's no real issue there. It's probably better to use PaymentMethods though(but unfortunately a lot of the Billing-specific documentation hasn't been updated for that). You can replace all the `createToken`s with `createPaymentMethod`, and set https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method on the sub